# Windows Form App Crashing With While Loops

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

First of all I would like to apologize for the **messy** code. Currently in my freshman year of college and had a question neither myself or my friends could figure out. The problem asks to accept an input from the user for dollars and find how many twenties, tens, fives, and ones will add to the least number of bills. Building the solution causes **no error**, but once ran and data is input it **crashes** instantly. I tried using the debugger to no avail, as well as changing the code (adding 'if' 'then' statements, etc.) I'm generally new to 'while' loops, and coding in general, so if I am making a stupid mistake feel free to roast me.
Thank you in advanced!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dollars
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnFindDem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int twenties;
        int tens;
        int fives;
        int singles;
        int totDollars;
        int sub1;
        int sub2;
        int sub3;
        int sub4;
        totDollars = Convert.ToInt32(txtDollars.Text);
        twenties = 0;
        tens = 0;
        fives = 0;
        singles = 0;
        sub1 = totDollars;
        sub2 = totDollars;
        sub3 = totDollars;
        sub4 = totDollars;
        lstOut.Items.Add("Total dollars = " + totDollars.ToString("c"));
            while (totDollars >= 20)
                {
                    sub1 = sub1 - 20;
                    twenties = twenties + 1;
                }
            while (totDollars >= 10)
                {
                    sub2 = sub2 - 10;
                    tens = tens + 1;
                }
            while (totDollars >= 5)
                {
                    sub3 = sub3 - 5;
                    fives = fives + 1;
                }
            while (totDollars >= 1)
                {
                    sub4 = sub4 - 1;
                    singles = singles + 1;
                }
        lstOut.Items.Add("Twenties: " + twenties);
        lstOut.Items.Add("Tens: " + tens);
        lstOut.Items.Add("Fives: " + fives);
        lstOut.Items.Add("Ones: " + singles);




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash". What exception is being reported? What happens when you run with debugger from Visual Studio?

Comment: All I get is 'Not Responding' and it just sits there until I end the process.

Comment: why are you subtracting from those `sub` variables instead of `totDollars`? Since you don't subtract from `totDollars`, your first loop will be infinite.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now that you mentioned it. I did say I was pretty new lol. Leave it as an answer and I'll choose it as the correct one. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. Everybody was new to programming at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adjusting the value of the variable you are using in the while loop conditions. This:

```
sub1 = totDollars;
sub2 = totDollars;
sub3 = totDollars;
sub4 = totDollars;
lstOut.Items.Add("Total dollars = " + totDollars.ToString("c"));
    while (totDollars >= 20)
        {
            sub1 = sub1 - 20;
            twenties = twenties + 1;
        }
```

should be

```
lstOut.Items.Add("Total dollars = " + totDollars.ToString("c"));
    while (totDollars >= 20)
        {
            totDollars = totDollars - 20;
            twenties = twenties + 1;
        }
```

and the similar change made to the other while loops

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the value in txtDollars.Text is indeed an integer, or else the program will crash;

The conditions being used by the while loops to continue are never changing.  So the while loop will never end.

```
while (totDollars >= 20)
{
    sub1 = sub1 - 20;
    twenties = twenties + 1;
}
```

totDollars never changes, so it'll always be greater than 20 and never end.  The quick way around this is to remove the sub variables like the following.

```
while (totDollars >= 20)
{
    totDollars = totDollars - 20;
    twenties = twenties + 1;
}
```

I've also included another version of the method, with some code optimizations. You'll notice the use of the -=, ++, and -- operators. It's really handy to know these.  Also, note there are some neat ways you can declare a variable and set the value in one step.

```
private void btnFindDem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int twenties = 0, 
        tens = 0, 
        fives = 0, 
        singles = 0,
        totDollars = Convert.ToInt32(txtDollars.Text);
    lstOut.Items.Add("Total dollars = " + totDollars.ToString("c"));
    while (totDollars >= 20)
    {
        totDollars -= 20;
        twenties++;
    }
    while (totDollars >= 10)
    {
        totDollars -= 10;
        tens++;
    }
    while (totDollars >= 5)
    {
        totDollars-= 5;
        fives++;
    }
    while (totDollars >= 1)
    {
        totDollars--;
        singles++;
    }
    lstOut.Items.Add("Twenties: " + twenties);
    lstOut.Items.Add("Tens: " + tens);
    lstOut.Items.Add("Fives: " + fives);
    lstOut.Items.Add("Ones: " + singles);
}
```

Comment: I would upvote if my account wasn't too new. Thank you as well!